# how router object of express.js is parsed to app.use() which accept callbacks only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module.exports

how router object of express.js is parsed to app.use() which accept callbacks only as router is an object of express , I want to understand why app.use() is not throwing an error even if router is a object and app.use() demands callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`app.use` documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use):

> **`callback`**
>
> Callback functions; can be:
>
> - A middleware function.
> - A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).
> - An array of middleware functions.
>
> A combination of all of the above.
>
> ...
>
> **Since [`router`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) and [`app`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#application) implement the middleware interface, you can use them as you would any other middleware function.**

*(my emphasis at the end)*

So that's the answer. Both `app` and `router` are functions, and they follow the middleware protocol when you call them. (Remember that functions in JavaScript are objects, so they can have properties and methods on them.)